# Low CPU usage with Parallel.ForEach(...)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core

I'm attempting to parallelize a task but I'm not getting good performance. At most I'm getting 50% CPU usage.

Below is a toy example where I build a list of lists of random words, and then go through every word and string reverse it. The reversing part is what I'm trying to parallelize.

To me this looks like a CPU-bound problem, so I don't really understand why CPU usage is so low.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Papa
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Build source
            var random = new Random();
            var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

            Console.WriteLine("Building data source");
            var source = new List<string[]>();
            foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 5000000))
            {
                var words = random.Next(3, 50);
                var line = new List<string>();

                for (var j = 0; j < words; ++j)
                {
                    line.Add(
                        string.Concat(
                            Enumerable
                                .Range(0, random.Next(3, 9))
                                .Select(w => alphabet[random.Next(0, alphabet.Length - 1)])
                        )
                    );
                }

                source.Add(line.ToArray());
            }

            // Process source
            Console.WriteLine("Processing source");
            var processed = new List<string[]>();
            Parallel.ForEach(
                source,
                () => new List<string[]>(),
                (line, loop, local) =>
                {
                    var processedLine = new List<string>();
                    for (var i = 0; i < line.Count(); ++i)
                    {
                        processedLine.Add(string.Concat(line[i].Reverse()));
                    }

                    local.Add(processedLine.ToArray());
                    return local;
                },
                partitionResult =>
                {
                    lock (processed)
                    {
                        processed.AddRange(partitionResult);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the "50%" utilization is already in the parallel part and not in the data generation part?

Comment: Yes, 50% during the processing part, in the initial stage it's much lower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` will use as many threads as the scheduler provides by default ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)). Be aware that the documentation states:

> Executes a foreach (For Each in Visual Basic) operation on a Partitioner in which iterations may run in parallel and loop options can be configured.

So it might be the case it just does not seem fit with the default options.

After running your code I found the following (when hitting the parallelized part):

[image]

As you can see it already utilized 15Gb of memory but it's running on all cores. I'm quite sure you run into memory/GC bottlenecks rather than CPU bottlenecks.

I run some additional performance analysis. This is what I found (`String::Concat` can be ignored because it's part of the initialization):

[image]

Line 45 is taking up ~50% of the CPU time.

[image]

I played a bit with the code and made the following changes:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
             source,
             () => new List<string[]>(),
             (line, loop, local) =>
             {
                 var length = line.Length;
                 var processedLine = new string[length];
                 for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i)
                 {
                     processedLine[i] = line[i].Reverse() + "";
                 }

                 local.Add(processedLine);
                 return local;
             },
             partitionResult =>
             {
                 lock (processed)
                 {
                     processed.AddRange(partitionResult);
                 }
             });
```

With a doubled data-size (`10000000` ~32Gb of data) this shows at least a small peak in CPU usage but it is done in less than **7 seconds** so I'm not quite sure that TaskManager really gets the peak correctly. Never the less this does also not resolve the problem and the GC also runs like crazy.

My "final" conclusion would be, that it's either (or multiple) of:

- GC
- Memory
- Cache misses

which is throttling you.

In my opinion, this is a nice example of why parallelization will not yield *x*-times the performance even if you can use *x*-threads.

Comment: I have 6 physical and 12 logical cores. Setting MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 12 does nothing for performance.

Comment: @mpium: There is is a ton of memory in use and the GC is running like crazy (see the yellow line int he diagnostics). I think this causes your problems. Please see my edit.

Comment: It does seem like it. Tried to reduce the memory by reusing the line array instead of creating a new one, but the act of reversing the string alone seems to be causing a lot of GC.

Comment: Tried reducing the loop but still GC is in overdrive, so not sure how this can be implemented efficiently. `for (var i = 0; i < line.Count(); ++i) { line[i] = string.Concat(line[i].Reverse()); }`

Comment: @mpium: I'm not sure you will be able to resolve this problem in an easy manner. There are multiple factors at play (GC, Memory bandwidth, Cache misses) which might cause the problem. All CPU-Cores are "in-use" but there still other stuff around that is holding them back. Getting this right will be a tedious task at best and nearly impossible (or not worth the time) at worst.

Comment: The ton of memory is probably due to the number of strings that are being created by concatenation when creating the words, and in the parallel foreach when reversing the words. You'd be better off with a char[] and doing in-place reversal. That will severely cut down the number of string creations.

Comment: @insane_developer: `String::Reverse` works on `IEnumeration<char>`. So it's not reversing this as junks of strings and therefore not concatenating them every char it's processing. Nevertheless, you need to get it back into a string and that's why the ` + ""` is present.

Comment: @Alex yes, I saw that when I actually ran the code. I figure doing `line[i].Reverse() + ""` and  `string.Concat(line[i].Reverse())` would be the exact same in terms of performance.

Comment: @insane_developer I replaced my string reversal with an unsafe function that does it in-place and performance jumped to close to 80% on all cores. So the ton of garbage generated during string reversal has something to do with it. I came across the this function on a blog post article [https://philosopherdeveloper.com/posts/are-strings-really-immutable-in-net.html](https://philosopherdeveloper.com/posts/are-strings-really-immutable-in-net.html). Clearly it shouldn't be used in production.

Comment: @mpium: Nice catch. I also didn't know that.

Comment: @mpium I think `unsafe` blocks are there for a reason. You should never think about using them unless you really know what you're doing.